# Distributing in-house iOS app to a company

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, in-house-distribution

Our company is enrolled in the Enterprise iOS Developer Program and we are making an ios application for another company that will be used on many mobile devices.

The other company also have an Enterprise license so I was wondering how we should distribute our application. The easiest way I could come up with is that we send our application as an .ipa-file to the other company and then they will have to distribute it on their own.

What I am wondering is:

- Are we breaking any apply license agreement here?
- If not, is it possible to distribute it this way to several companies?

Comment: This question is off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are breaking the license agreement.
With your enterprise license you can only distribute the apps to your company employees
If you want to distribute the app to other enterprise employees you should sign it with their enterprise account.

When you create the ipa, there is a checkbox "Save for enterprise distribution", check it and it will create a plist file, then upload that plist and your ipa to any webserver and an index.html with this

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://yourweb.com/thePlistYouCreatedBefore.plist">Install app</a></body></html>
```